# The backup file should be restored to a server with version '14.0.0.6117' or later

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to restore the SharePoint 2010 portal from one server to another server and using the sharepoint 2010 backup and restore powershell commands. I have take the backup successfully, while restoring I'm getting the following error.

Error:

```
"Restore-SPSite : Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft 
 SharePoint Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the 
 current version. The backup file should be restored to a server with 
 version '14.0.0.6117' or later"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1) Download the hot fix from this link by register your Email id
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597150

2) Extract the file and run the exe
   Note: don't run the SharePoint 2010 Configuration wizard during the installation...

3) After successful installation Restart your system.

4) Run SharePoint 2010 Configuration wizard setup.

5) Start the restore operation once again your problem get resolved

- Some time you will get rendering error

To resolve this issue go to central administration then open
farm config and start the state service

Comment: In short, you need to update your Sharepoint Foundation to at least the same version as the backup source.

Comment: Different application may run in one Sharepoint Foundation know its may impact.